# Owin application configuration with Castle TypedFactory

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api2, owin, castle

I have a WebAPI application with Owin and Castle configured. That application will be hosted on IIS (So I install package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb)

I would like to configure a token based authentication and have a customized OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider that will use a Castle TypedFactoryFacility(I remove that code in provided sample as it does not cause the error).

Here is Startup class code of my Owin application

```
    public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        //_windsorContainer.Install(FromAssembly.This());
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(Component.For<AuthorizationServerProvider>());
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorCompositionRoot(container));

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            Provider = container.Resolve<AuthorizationServerProvider>()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWebApi(config);

    } }
```

WindsorCompositionRoot is the implentation proposed by Mark Seemann : http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/

When I try to debug my application I got the following error :

> No component for supporting the service System.Threading.Tasks.Task was found

And here is the corresponding stacktrace

> [ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service System.Threading.Tasks.Task was found]
>      Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) +106 
>   Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryComponentResolver.Resolve(IKernelInternal kernel, IReleasePolicy scope) +307
>
> Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Resolve(IInvocation
>   invocation) +256
>   Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation
>   invocation) +265 Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +484
>   Castle.Proxies.Func'2Proxy.Invoke(OAuthMatchEndpointContext arg) +174 
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext
>   context) +59
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.d__0.MoveNext() +693
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +24 Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +664 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +287 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +272 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +22 Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +150
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +42
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +415 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

If I do not add TypedFactoryFacility to my container my project work without that error ...

Why Castle is injecting a TypedFactory in that place ? What can I do to avoid that error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Samy and Phil Degenhardt tips, here is a way to force castle to not fill OnMatchEndpoint property and make it work :

```
container.Register(Component.For<AuthorizationServerProvider>()
            .PropertiesIgnore((m, p) => p.PropertyType == typeof(Func<OAuthMatchEndpointContext, Task>)));
```

Comment: While this will work, it's rather brittle. Start using other OAuth features and you will find it breaks again and you will have to come back and revisit this. OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider is a long lived class and needs to orchestrate a variety of different functions, which may do things like require db connections. Rather than putting OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider in your container, another approach would be to instead implement other/classes that can be safely registered and have OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider delegate to these. It's a little more verbose but more robust.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as an answer, but it is rather some avenues you may want to investigate.

I've had some bad surprises with the `TypedFactoryFacility` when using it, since it tried to resolve any `Func<>` and/or Lazy<> type property or constructor parameter to a typed factory. You may have one of these types in your component that castle is trying to resolve.

If this is the case, you may need to configure the resolution explicitly as shown in the [Typed factory facility](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-delegate-based.md) page. An alternative is to [remove the `DelegateFactory` from the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987323/can-windsors-typedfactoryfacilitys-implicit-delegate-factory-registration-be-d)

Comment: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider has a bunch of Func<x,Task> properties.  One of those is OnMatchEndpoint that is called by MatchEndpoint(), which appears in the callstack above. So I believe your answer is spot on Samy.